# Install OpenBLAS libs in alternative system

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I compiled OpenBLAS and istalled it in /usr/lib/libopenblas
Now I want to install the libraries in the alternatives system running

```
#!/bin/bash

update-alternatives 
--install  /usr/lib/libblas.so  libblas.so  /usr/lib/libopenblas
 /lib/libopenblas.so  40\
--slave-link  /usr/lib/libblas.a   libblas.a  /usr/lib/libopenblas
/lib/libopenblas.a

update-alternatives 
--install/usr/lib/libblas.so.3 libblas.so.3  
/usr/lib/libopenblas/lib/libopenblas.so.0  40\
--slave-link /usr/lib/libblas.so.3gf libblas.so.3gf 
/usr/lib/libopenblas/lib/libopenblas.so.0
```

but always get the error

```
update-alternatives: priority must be an integer
```

while I believe that I set this priority to the number 40.
What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenBLAS is a Debian / Ubuntu package, so you could

- install the existing one
- use the source of the existing ones to build a local one

and in either case it will have the `postinst` script with

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 libblas.so.3 \                                                                                                                                                  
        /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3 40 \                                                                                                                                                                    
    --slave /usr/lib/libblas.so.3gf libblas.so.3gf /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3                                                                                                                              

update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3 liblapack.so.3 \                                                                                                                                              
        /usr/lib/openblas-base/liblapack.so.3 40 \                                                                                                                                                                  
    --slave /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf liblapack.so.3gf /usr/lib/openblas-base/liblapack.so.3
```

Comment: I corrected my script replacing --slave-link with --slave It now looks exactly like yours, but to no avail, the priority numner is not recognized.

Comment: Finally I figured it out: a space is needed after 40 or else the line reads ...40--slave... How dumb!!!

Comment: Ah, yes, the little things.  Sorry for not noticing earlier.  Been bitten by that too once or twice.  Live and learn :)